# Get a value in a numpy array from a index in a variable

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I am trying to access a value in a multi dimensional numpy array.
This can be easily done when you know everything, for exemple :

`T = numpy.arrange(9).reshape(3, 3)
T[2, 2]`

And it returns 8, which is what I want.
Now, Let's assume `[2, 2]` is stored in `index` variable.
How can I do to take the value in T with the index stored in `index` ?
I would like to do 
`T[index]` but it returns the last row twice (pretty logical but not what I want).

Thank you !

Comment: Try `ind=tuple(2,2); x[ind]`

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
ind=tuple(2,2)
x[ind]
```

`x[2,2]` is the same as `x[(2,2)]` which is translated into a method call: `x.__getitem__((2,2))`.

Some `numpy` functions build an index as a list or array, then convert it to a `tuple` for use in the index.

Comment: If you want to access multiple values at once, make sure to use a 2-tuple which consists of two arrays: first for x-values, second for y-values respectively. If you have a list of indices in format `p=[[x0,y0],[x1,y1], ... ]` for the 2d array `D`, just use `indx=tuple(np.transpose(p))` which is `([x0,x1,..],[y0,y1,...])` and access via `D[indx]`.